# limit for integral of a bounded continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a bounded continuous function on $\mathbb R$. Prove that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb R} \dfrac {f(t)}{1+n^{2}t^{2}} dt=f(0)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** change the variable: $u = nt$. Then use the dominated convergence theorem.
You are left using 
$$
\int \frac {dx}{1+x^2} = [\arctan]_{-\infty}^\infty = \pi
$$